# Xcode|LLDB: thread jump -b 1 inside closure

Tags: xcode, lldb

I have the following code that uses RxSwift and RxCocoa.  The problem I'm having is that when I try to set a breakpoint that jumps a line with the lldb command `thread jump -b 1`, I get error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7fb8ecc0b9).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonPressedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    private var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func buttonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let closure = { [unowned self] in
            print("1st line of closure")
            self.counter += 1
            self.buttonPressedLabel.text = "Button Pressed \(self.counter) times"
            print("2nd line of closure")
        }
        closure()
    }


}
```

Is there anything extra that needs to be done when trying to skip lines of code inside a closure or execute code in a closure through breakpoints?

Answer (score 1):

I talked a little bit about the dangers of `thread jump` in the answer to:

[breakpoint with debugger Commend jump in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738228/breakpoint-with-debugger-commend-jump-in-xcode)

Whether or not, and how, you get in trouble from skipping code depends on the code you skip.  If you really want to understand the issues, you need to look at the disassembly of the code you are skipping.  But compiled code is generally not in self-contained units some of which are optional.  So while this is a useful technique, it is not always guaranteed to succeed.